# Ajax price filter Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Ajax Code:

```
function showProduct(baseurl,sortbyid)
{
    //alert('123');
if (sortbyid=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("sortMyData").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("sortMyData").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }               
      url = baseurl + 'product/sortby/'+sortbyid; 
      //alert(url); 
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();   
    return false;
  }
```

Controller:

```
public function sortby()
        {
            $lowhigh=$this->uri->segment(3);
            $lowtohighprice=$this->product_model->getlowtohighprice($lowhigh);
            $this->load->view('sortby');
        }
```

Model:

public function getlowtohighprice()
    {
        $lowtohighQuery=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product group by price order by price ASC");

```
    if($lowtohighQuery->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach($lowtohighQuery->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $lowtohighpricedetails[]=$row;
        }
    return $lowtohighpricedetails; 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the products from low to high price using ajax filter.I have executed query, its working fine. I am new to ajax so i hope the prob with ajax code .I don noe where i am stuck, am using codeigniter framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your data to the view, so the view can show you the query result.

```
public function sortby()
{
    $lowhigh = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $lowtohighprice = $this->product_model->getlowtohighprice($lowhigh);

    // The second parameter $lowtohighprice is the data
    $this->load->view('sortby', $lowtohighprice); 
}
```